OutOfMemory Excpetion when write a large txt file vb.net
In my program recovering data from the db (there are over 500k lines) I create a path with this data and write it in a file (in the db as a where clause I insert what the date range is, the lower it is the less data I recover, obviously... .), I tested 360 days and the rows it recovers are over 500k, this is the modification I made to my previous code (it already gave that error) and up to 250/350k rows no problem
For Each dtrT As DataRow In dttTmp.Rows
    sbFile.Append(company & "§" & dtrT!type & "|" &
                  company & "|" &
                  strKeyNumReg & "|" &
                  ConvStr(dtrT!tm_numdoc) & "|" &
                  ConvStr(dtrT!xx_codart) & "|" &
                  ConvStr(dtrT!mm_row) & "|" &
                  (ConvStr(dtrT!mm_codart) & IIf(NTSCStr(dtrT!mm_fase) <> "0", "." & ConvStr(dtrT!mm_fase), "").ToString).Trim & "|" &
                  (ConvStr(dtrT!mm_descr) & " " & ConvStr(dtrT!mm_desint, True)).Trim & desc & "|" &
                  ConvStr(dtrT!mm_ump) & "|" &
                  ConvDec(dtrT!mm_quant).ToString("0.00000") & "|" &
                  "0" & "|" &
                  ConvDec(dtrT!xx_price).ToString("0.0000") & "|" &
                  ConvDec(dtrT!mm_value).ToString("0.00") & "|" &
                  ConvDec(dtrT!mm_disc1).ToString("0.00") & "|" &
                  ConvDec(dtrT!mm_disc2).ToString("0.00") & "|" &
                  IIf(ConvStr(dtrT!an_type) = "C", 0, 1).ToString & "|" &
                  ConvStr(dtrT!an_costumer) & "|" &
                  ConvStr(dtrT!tm_currency) & "|" &
                  ConvStr(dtrT!cod_dest) & "|" &
                  ConvData(dtrT!data_cons) & "|" &
                  ConvDec(dtrT!xx_cod_state_row) & "|" &
                  GetDescription(ConvDec(dtrT!xx_cod_state_row)) & "|" &
                  ConvData(dtrT!xx_lastupdate) & vbCrLf )
Next

If dttTmp.Rows.Count > 0 Then
    Using sw As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(strFileOut, False, Encoding.UTF8)
        Const bufferSize As Integer = 10000
        Dim buffer As Char() = New Char(9999) {}
        Dim i As Integer = 0

        While i < sbFile.Length
            Dim count As Integer = Math.Min(bufferSize, sbFile.Length - i)
            sbFile.CopyTo(i, buffer, 0, count)
            sw.Write(buffer, 0, count)
            i += bufferSize
        End While
    End Using
End If


Which line does it raise the exception on?

sbFile.Append raise the exception

You seem to be building the entire file in memory, then writing it out to disk at once. Try writing directly to file instead, so you only need the current line in memory

Also, you might want to read the data from the database in batches to avoid running out of memory when populating the DataTable (or similar).

Write each line to the file as you read it from the DataTable. You can skip the StringBuilder entirely.
Using sw As New StreamWriter(strFileOut, False, Encoding.UTF8)
    For Each dtrT As DataRow In dttTmp.Rows
        sw.WriteLine(
            company & "§" & dtrT!type & "|" &
            company & "|" &
            strKeyNumReg & "|" &
            ConvStr(dtrT!tm_numdoc) & "|" &
            ConvStr(dtrT!xx_codart) & "|" &
            ConvStr(dtrT!mm_row) & "|" &
            (ConvStr(dtrT!mm_codart) & IIf(NTSCStr(dtrT!mm_fase) <> "0", "." & ConvStr(dtrT!mm_fase), "").ToString).Trim & "|" &
            (ConvStr(dtrT!mm_descr) & " " & ConvStr(dtrT!mm_desint, True)).Trim & desc & "|" &
            ConvStr(dtrT!mm_ump) & "|" &
            ConvDec(dtrT!mm_quant).ToString("0.00000") & "|" &
            "0" & "|" &
            ConvDec(dtrT!xx_price).ToString("0.0000") & "|" &
            ConvDec(dtrT!mm_value).ToString("0.00") & "|" &
            ConvDec(dtrT!mm_disc1).ToString("0.00") & "|" &
            ConvDec(dtrT!mm_disc2).ToString("0.00") & "|" &
            IIf(ConvStr(dtrT!an_type) = "C", 0, 1).ToString & "|" &
            ConvStr(dtrT!an_costumer) & "|" &
            ConvStr(dtrT!tm_currency) & "|" &
            ConvStr(dtrT!cod_dest) & "|" &
            ConvData(dtrT!data_cons) & "|" &
            ConvDec(dtrT!xx_cod_state_row) & "|" &
            GetDescription(ConvDec(dtrT!xx_cod_state_row)) & "|" &
            ConvData(dtrT!xx_lastupdate))
    Next
End Using

